# How to pass data from parent controller to child controller in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I have a parent controller named 'MyClass' in this class have index function that have the below code:

```
            $this->children = array(
                'common/footer',
                'common/header'
                'live/live'
            );
```

I want to send some data from MyClass => index function to child controller(live). This data will be dynamic.

So please  can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the actual classes involved, and how they are called. Probably you just need to call the parent method in the overridden child method `parent::index();`

Comment: I am using opencart Version 1.5.6.4.

Comment: Steve: I have an url 'product/search?name=abc' that land on Search Controller. In Search Controller Index function I have this piece of code:
$this->children = array(
                'common/footer',
                'common/header'
                'live/live'
            );
'data/listing' => means now we lands to listing Controller(resides in data directory) that is child controller of Search Controller.

I have some data in Search Controller that need to pass in listing Controller for further use.

Comment: Actually I want to develop a common tpl file for data lisiting with dynamic data. The lisitng (child controller will also call from other controllers like Search controller)